# How do i produce multiple tableView header titles?

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom cell that includes 3 parts (Sales Rep, Prize, Signed) 
(See image below)

I want to have three titles on my tableView header but I only know how to add one title with the built-in method. Can someone help me?

[image]

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"My Title";
{
```

Comment: you must return no of section 3 ; in this method "- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own view to show as a section header, instead of letting the OS create one for you based on the text you want within it. This allows you full customisation as to what you want contained within a section header.

You can do this by returning a view within the delegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

If you want the section headers split per row, then you'll need to have multiple sections. 1 section header exists for each section, so if you want 3 headers, then you'll need to have 3 sections. You can tell the table the number of sections you want via:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Then in delegate methods which provide a section index integer, you use that to differentiate between sections. If they provide an index path instead, you can get the section number via `indexPath.section`

Comment: you must return no of section 3 ; in this method "- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView"

Comment: I tried this but I don't see a way to do more than one header this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  UIView *view = nil;
  UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];
  CGFloat x=0;
  for (int i = 0;i<[list count];i++)
  {
    id val=[list objectAtIndex:i];
    CGFloat val1=[val floatValue];
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0,107,40)];

    newLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",list[i]];

    newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    newLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    newLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    newLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    [header addSubview:newLabel];

    x=x+newLabel.frame.size.width;


}

return header;
}
```

Comment: Use for loop add one by one into header.. Set Table view size based on header view size.. Thats it.